# AWS Amplify Console command returns "Cannot read property 'awscloudformation' of undefined"

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-amplify, aws-amplify-cli

I am using the AWS Amplify-CLI to try and launch the Amplify Console from the root of my project. I type the following:

```
> amplify console
```

And get the following error:

```
Cannot read property 'awscloudformation' of undefined
```

Answer (score 0):

I have two Amplify environments: test and prod. In git, I had switched from the test branch to prod. However, it seems Amplify (current version: 5.3.1) does not pick up on this. Instead you get the above unhelpful error message.

I figured it out with the help of this github issue: https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-cli/issues/1734#issuecomment-506435290

Once I ran `amplify env checkout prod`, I was able to launch the console as before.